# check two tables, if one has less rows - then add rows in

Tags: r

Hi I am running the following r script over many files in a folder

```
runForAll <- function(x) {
  emboss <- read.table(x,header=T)
  x <- table(emboss[,2],emboss[,3])/NROW(emboss[,3])
  y <- as.vector(t(x))
  nms <- expand.grid(colnames(x), rownames(x))
  names(y) <- paste( nms[,2],nms[,1],sep="")
  return(t(y))
}
my.files <- list.files(pattern = "emboss_\\d+\\.ss")
outputs <- lapply(my.files, FUN = runForAll)
```

where I notice that in x, some of the tables have 1 less row than some others.

normal x:

```
          C           E           H
  A 0.011152416 0.003717472 0.011152416
  C 0.026022305 0.033457249 0.003717472
  D 0.029739777 0.000000000 0.007434944
  E 0.044609665 0.011152416 0.003717472
  F 0.022304833 0.011152416 0.011152416
  G 0.026022305 0.003717472 0.007434944
  H 0.040892193 0.007434944 0.003717472
  I 0.040892193 0.022304833 0.022304833
  K 0.059479554 0.003717472 0.018587361
  L 0.018587361 0.007434944 0.066914498
  M 0.003717472 0.003717472 0.011152416
  N 0.052044610 0.003717472 0.007434944
  P 0.044609665 0.000000000 0.003717472
  Q 0.018587361 0.000000000 0.014869888
  R 0.026022305 0.007434944 0.011152416
  S 0.022304833 0.007434944 0.011152416
  T 0.029739777 0.014869888 0.014869888
  V 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.014869888
  W 0.011152416 0.007434944 0.007434944
  Y 0.018587361 0.029739777 0.022304833
```

x with missing row:

```
           C           E           H
  A 0.030874786 0.012006861 0.049742710
  D 0.044596913 0.005145798 0.015437393
  E 0.029159520 0.008576329 0.024013722
  F 0.013722127 0.015437393 0.005145798
  G 0.051457976 0.003430532 0.008576329
  H 0.013722127 0.005145798 0.006861063
  I 0.024013722 0.015437393 0.013722127
  K 0.056603774 0.003430532 0.039451115
  L 0.025728988 0.024013722 0.039451115
  M 0.006861063 0.003430532 0.010291595
  N 0.029159520 0.001715266 0.008576329
  P 0.036020583 0.001715266 0.008576329
  Q 0.020583190 0.005145798 0.015437393
  R 0.037735849 0.008576329 0.020583190
  S 0.030874786 0.005145798 0.027444254
  T 0.034305317 0.006861063 0.017152659
  V 0.010291595 0.012006861 0.018867925
  W 0.006861063 0.000000000 0.010291595
  Y 0.005145798 0.008576329 0.006861063
```

How can I check that:

> each instance of x has 20 rows
>   and if a particular instance of x has less than 20 rows
>   add in a row(s) full of zeros

ie if one x has only 17 rows, add 3 rows of zeros.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it:

```
x = data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = 1, C = 1)
x[head(seq(nrow(x)+1, 21), -1),] = 0
```